# What does it mean for a SOCKS5 proxy to have UDP enabled?

Tags: networking, proxy, udp, socks-proxy, socks5

[v2ray](https://www.v2ray.com/en/configuration/protocols/socks.html) has options for enabling UDP for a socks5 server. What does this mean? How is it usable? How can I test the server to see if it is working correctly?

Comment: UDP is a network protocol (at the Transmission layer), like its sibling TCP. Enabling it will allow you to proxy UDP traffic. not sure what more there is to say about it.

Comment: @FrankThomas How do I test if it's working correctly? As far as I can see, most tools don't touch UDP.

Comment: *"How do I test if it's working correctly?"* - use a client which supports proxying UDP over socks5 and check if it works. I'm not sure what the purpose of the question is: you don't seem to have an actual use case where you need to proxy UDP in the first place - otherwise it would be quite clear what the purpose of proxying it and how to test it.

Comment: torrents use udp for some connections, and often have proxy configuration available in the client, so perhaps select a client, point it at your proxy and try to download a linux distro.